# List Of Text And Clickable

Tags: android

I want to ask how to make a list of text that we can tap in each of the text and then get the selected text to editText.
I just added the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddZSg.png

I have been searching it since yesterday, but I can not find exact solution. I also tried with  listview, but I don't know how it's possible with horizontal, and flow list item.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? If mine achieved what you were trying to do, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just activated email notifications in Setting. So I will receive your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: mind giving my answer an upvote at least, instead of accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new in android. But I can think of the logic what you want. You can try this out if you want.

1. First of all, you can make your list of texts `EditText` by list of buttons `Buttons`
2. You can dynamically add as many Buttons with their respective `text` as you want to show.
3. set their corresponding **onClickListener**
4. In their **onClickListener** , create an object of the `EditText` you are using to add texts.
5. Store the value of `EditText` into a String Variable first.
6. Add the text of the **clicked**  `Button` to the variable.
7. and now again set the text in `EditText` with the **variable** you created to store the values.
8. Your task will be done.

Try referring this code.
and change the code accordingly as your needs.

```
     // Adding EditText and a button in a new linear layout and then adding
    // the new linearLayout to the main layout

    String[] valuesToBeAdded={"A","B","C","D"};
    String selectedValues=null;

    LinearLayout mainLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);


    LinearLayout localLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    localLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    localLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    EditText editText=new EditText(context);
    editText.setText(selectedValues);
    editText.setId(5000);

    localLayout.addView(editText);

    for(int i=0;i<valuesToBeAdded.length();i++){

    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText(R.string.scanDocument);
    button.setId(i);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText ed=(EditText) findViewById(5000);
            selectedValues=ed.getText();
            selectedValues=selectedValues +" " + this.getText();

            ed.setText(selectedValues);
        }
    });


    localLayout.addView(button);

    }
    mainLayout.addView(localLayout);
```

Thank You

Comment: I have dynamic data as like tags in example above. So I have to make the buttons programmatically. I got your point, but I'm still confused about how to get the view and put the buttons in existing layout and in specific area.

Comment: Wow yeah, this nearly does the job, can you help me a little bit more? Linear layout can not make new row automatically when there are too many buttons. (I'm using horizontal orientation here) Is there any alternative rather than using Linear Layout?

Comment: yes...you can use `RelativeLayout` rather than `LinearLayout` 
try referring for it online.. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just found the answer, using flow layout.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you not make as many buttons as you need and then in the button_Click method for all buttons add:

```
    Buttonwithtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editTextBox.Text = editTextBox.Text + Buttonwithtext.text + ", ":
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, can you give some examples in real implementation of android? How do you manage buttons in layout?

Comment: @Huteri Sorry, I'm at a loss when it comes to android stuff :(.

Comment: oh, it's okay. I appreciate you was trying to help me.